# Javascript Algorithm - If the subtraction of indices is negative, return as elements of array as possible

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Imagine a list of items:

```
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

One variable represents the main item:

```
const initialIndex = 1;
```

And the other variable, the number of extra elements that will also be collected behind of the "main item".

```
const extraCount = 2;
```

So, if for example, I call the method "algorithm" as follows:

```
function algorithm(data, initialIndex, extraCount) { ... }


console.log(algorithm(data, 2, 1));
```

It will return me `[1, 2]` // The initial index and the first element behind it

Or, if for example I call again with

```
console.log(algorithm(data, 4, 3));
```

It will return me `[1, 2, 3, 4]` // The initial element and 3 items behind it

How can I do, in a simple way, to fix this use case

```
 console.log(algorithm(data, 1, 2)); // Negative index...
```

But... I need to return at least the possible items.

I mean:

For `console.log(algorithm(data, 1, 2));` I get `[0, 1]` // Initial index, and the first item before (not two because the second one has a negative index)

For `console.log(algorithm(data, 2, 5));` I get `[0, 1, 2]`

For `console.log(algorithm(data, 0, 10));` I get `[0]`

For `console.log(algorithm(data, 3, 7));` I get `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

### EDIT

This is what I have tried

```js
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const initialIndex = 2;
const extraCount = 2;
    
const start = initialIndex - extraCount >= 0 ? initialIndex - extraCount : initialIndex;

const end = initialIndex + 1;

console.log(data.slice(start, end));
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it correct. Just replace `initialIndex` by `0` in else condition

```js
const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

let func = (initialIndex,extraCount) => {
    
const start = initialIndex - extraCount >= 0 ? initialIndex - extraCount : 0;

const end = initialIndex + 1;

console.log(data.slice(start, end));

};

func(2,2);
func(1,2);
func(3,7);
```

**Note:** There are a lot of other ways to do it, but this is the one you were going for so I just pointed out the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice(-count)` to return elements from the end of array, something like this:

```js
if (extraCount > initialIndex) {
  return [
    // This will return elemnts from beginning of array up to initialIndex
    ...data.slice(0, initialIndex),

    // This will return the missing elements looped from the other side of array
    ...data.slice(extraCount - initialIndex)
  ];
}
```

You should also incorporate other sanity checks into your code, or example, total number of elements should not exceed array length, etc.